# xsl transform of dataset.writexml XML

Tags: xslt, dataset, transform, writexml

I have a scenario where I am exporting a .net dataset to an xml file, but I want to transform the stucture of the xml output to a more hierarchical structure. Below is the format of the dataset as exported by dataset.xmlwrite() method.

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <id>100</id>
        <empname>Joe Smith</empname>
        <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
        <mobile>222-222-2222</mobile>

    </Table>
    <Table>
        <id>101</id>
        <empname>Ann Jensen</empname>
        <phone>111-111-0000</phone>
        <mobile>222-222-0000</mobile>
    </Table>
<NewDataSet>
```

I want to convert it to the below structure. I am a newbie at xsl transforms and I am not sure how keep the `<Table>` element from repeating for every record in the dataset.

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <employee id="100">
            <empname>Joe Smith</empname>
            <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
            <mobile>222-222-2222</mobile>
        </employee>
        <employee id="101">
            <empname>Ann Jensen</empname>
            <phone>111-111-0000</phone>
            <mobile>222-222-0000</mobile>
        </employee>
    </Table>
<NewDataSet>
```

I tried using a combination of xsl:for-each and xsl:if statements to get what I wanted, but so far I have not been able to get it to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple and powerful solution that is fully in the spirit of XSLT: uses and overrides the identity rule. Note also that no conditional XSLT instructions are used at all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Table[1]">
  <Table>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="../Table/id"/>
  </Table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Table[position()>1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="Table/id">
  <employee id="{.}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "following-sibling::node()"/>
  </employee>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <id>100</id>
        <empname>Joe Smith</empname>
        <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
        <mobile>222-222-2222</mobile>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <id>101</id>
        <empname>Ann Jensen</empname>
        <phone>111-111-0000</phone>
        <mobile>222-222-0000</mobile>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<NewDataSet>
   <Table>
      <employee id="100">
         <empname>Joe Smith</empname>
         <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
         <mobile>222-222-2222</mobile>
      </employee>
      <employee id="101">
         <empname>Ann Jensen</empname>
         <phone>111-111-0000</phone>
         <mobile>222-222-0000</mobile>
      </employee>
   </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule copies every node "as-is".**
2. **The first `Table` element is matched by an overriding template**. This creates the only `Table` in the result and applies templates to the children of all `Table` elements.
3. **The `id` element is matched by an overriding template**, that converts it to an `employee` element having an `id` attribute with the value of the `id` element. This also applies templates from inside the `employee` element to all other siblings of `id` and they are copied as-is by the identity template.

Comment: @dvhh: Yes, XSLT is an extremely elegant and powerful language -- largely due to the "identity rule" design pattern.

Comment: It is clear I have a lot to learn about XSLT. I understand most of what you did (thanks for the explanation). But one clarification - The following-sibling::node() code selects all of the siblings to the id element - not just the immediate "following" sibling? I would not have expected that.

Comment: @Clinemi: Yes, the `following-sibling::` axis selects *all* nodes from the node-test that are following siblings of the context node. If you want only the first following sibling, you specify this, for example: `following-sibling::node()[1]`

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Better answer. But a little confuse... Wouldn't it be better something like `/` -> `NewDataSet`; `NewDataSet` -> `Table`; `Table` -> `employee`; `id` -> nothing?

Comment: @Alejandro: I am not sure I understand your question. I wrote this code aiming at it to be as short (in number of templates) as possible.

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Table>
    <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/Table">
        <employee>
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="id/."/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name() = 'id' "/>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </employee>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: don't mention it, my answer is a little bit simple compared to @Dimitre's one

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the looping solutions over the template based ones as I can get my head around them more readily and hence bend them to my will!